# ViewModel in recyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using `ViewModel` to load data and set it into `SwipeRefreshLayout RecyclerView`

```
    mAdapter = NewRecyclerViewAdapter(listAct, this@MainActivity, hashMap)
    list?.adapter = mAdapter

     workViewModel.getRequests()?.observe(
                this, Observer { resource ->
                    resource?.data?.let {
                        Log.d(TAG,it.size)
                        mAdapter.setOrders(it)
                    }
                }
            )

  workViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(
            this,
            ViewModelFactory.getInstance(activity.application)
        ).get(WorkViewModel::class.java)
                   .......


swipe_container.setOnRefreshListener {
            mAdapter.setWorkOrders(listAct)
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

I use the log to debug, it display size 2. Data seems successful to retrieve, but it did not set to the `recyclerView`.

**Adapter**

```
 private var order = emptyList<Order>()
     ......
     internal fun setOrders(order: List<Order>) {
            this.order = order
            this.order.sortedBy { it.created_at }
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

Comment: put notifyDataSetChanged() in Oberserver also

Comment: @HappySingh added, result still same

Comment: in setOrders() you are setting same order list. Use Orders instead of order

Comment: @HappySingh made a mistake there. Post updated.

Comment: Can you please post full code so it can be easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the same list in your setOrders() functions 
Use this instead of your function

```
internal fun setOrders(orders: List<Order>) {
    this.order = orders.sortedBy { it.created_at }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter )` anywhere ? Or better : have you initialized the recyclerview and than setting the adapter? Case you are using databinding check your adapter atribute in the recyclerview xml tag

Comment: yes,I did. Is on this line `list?.adapter = mAdapter`

Comment: Ok 2 things , in your RecyclerView check the getItemCount methot , it should not return 0 . And the other , please se the LayoutManager for your recyclerview : Example : rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context) and than set your adapter.

Comment: check recyclerview height and width

Comment: and a question , why are you passing map in the begining ?

Comment: I need to use that map inside `onBindView`

Comment: That is why I asked . Can you make sure that you are setting some values on the onBindViewHolder from the list that you are observing ?